# Is there a better way than this to sanitize hyperlinks from text inputs?

Tags: java, regex, string-parsing

I'm trying to remove any hyperlinks from given text and overwrite any fragments that appear to be hyperlinks, replacing them with the text `[LINK REMOVED FROM EVIDENCE AT REQUEST OF TRIAL JUDGE]`

```
public String overwriteLinks(String text){
    final String OVERWRITE_WITH = "[LINK REMOVED FROM EVIDENCE AT REQUEST OF TRIAL JUDGE]";

    List<String> checkForPatterns = Arrays.asList(
        "http://", "www", ".com", ".net", 
        ".org", "dot com", "dot net");

    StringBuilder re = new StringBuilder();
    for (String checkForPattern : checkForPatterns){
        if (re.length() > 0)
            re.append("|");
        String quotedSite = Pattern.quote(checkForPattern);
        re.append(quotedSite);
    }

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re.toString(),Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    text = p.matcher(text).replaceAll(OVERWRITE_WITH);

    return text;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this to maximize the number of links that are removed? My regex skills are iffy at best.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this regex:

```
public static final URI_REGEX = Pattern.compile( "^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?" );
```

I seem to remember importing/creating that one in our codebase from the URI RFC years ago. That should match all URIs in your string and allow easy replacement.

Comment: +1 for using the 3986 pattern.  Maybe note that group 1 contains the protocol and group 4 contains the authority.  Those are a good way to filter out valid relative URLs that are probably not links, for example `the`, and `a` are valid relative URLs.

Comment: Yeah - we use that to parse as well as validate, so the groups should represent the useful parts of the URL. It could easily be modified to require http(s):// at the head.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class following the example given by Lars Vogel in his [Java Regex Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#examples_linkchecker) ("6.4. Building a link checker") and then enhance it with a method to replace any of the links found with your OVERWRITE_WITH String.

You would have to tweak the example that Lars provides for your particular needs but then you would have a link processing class that you could use in other parts of your application as needed.